# Searching element in aray

Tags: java, indexing

I'm trying to create a program that asks the user the number of elements inside an array and prints its original list reverse list and assending. In, addition I'm also trying to find an element inside an array and print found and the index number if it is inside the array. So far here is my code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int n, y, z, temp=0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of elements you want to store here: ");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        int[] a = new int[10];
        System.out.println("Enter elements here: ");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
    
        System.out.print("\nOriginal list: ");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
        }
    
        System.out.print("\nReverse list: ");
        for(int i=n-1;i>=0;i--){
            System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
        }
        // it seems to copy the assending list. It should print the integers the way user entered it
        System.out.print("\nOriginal list: ");
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
        }
    
        for(y=0;y<n;y++){
            for(z=y+1;z<n;z++){
                if(a[y]>a[z]){
                    temp=a[y];
                    a[y]=a[z];
                    a[z]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
    
        {System.out.print("\nAscending Order list: ");
        for(y=0;y<n;y++){
            System.out.print(""+a[y]+" ");
        }}
        System.out.print("\nEnter the element you want to search: ");
        s = sc.nextInt();
        for(y=0;y<n;y++)
        {
        if(a[y]==s)
        {
        System.out.println("Element "+s+" is in "+y+" index");
        f=1;
        }
        }
        if(f==0)
        {
        System.out.println("Element "+s+" is not found");
        }
    } 
}
```

My problem is the last original list.

Comment: What is and sending? ascending??

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are taking an array not a list. Here you were not taking the user-defined array size. Rather you were taking an array of 10 elemets. Then you were swapping the elements of the original array. This caused the array elements to be rearranged. So, the original array got changed while you were swapping elements. In this case, you should take a copy of the array. And finding index numbers is pretty easy. Just loop over the elements and you are good to go. Hope this helps:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int n;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of elements you want to store here: ");
        n = sc.nextInt();

        int[] a = new int[n]; //Number of array member should be declared here

        System.out.println("Enter array elements here: ");

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.print("\nOriginal array: ");


        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
        }

        System.out.print("\nReverse array: ");

        for(int i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
        {
            System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
        }


        System.out.print("\nOriginal array: ");

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
        }


        //This is where you should make a copy of the original array. You are swapping variable. That's mean array is also getting swapped
        System.out.print("\nAscending Order array: ");

        int[] tempArray = a;
        Arrays.sort(tempArray);

        for (int j : tempArray)
        {
            System.out.print(j + " ");
        }

        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Enter the number you want to find: ");

        int toFind = sc.nextInt();

        boolean found = false;

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            if(a[i] == toFind)
            {
                found = true;
            }
        }

        if(found)
            System.out.println(toFind + " is found.");
        else
            System.out.println(toFind + " is not found.");
    }
```